# Как открыть браузер после запуска сервера на python

Tags: python, веб-сервер

Есть сервер, написанный на python, и html-файл, который требуется запускать, после того, как запустится сервер. Нужно, чтобы после того, как сервер запустится, автоматически открывался браузер и запускался  файл. Каким образом это можно сделать?
Код сервера:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPrequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        ...
def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    except:
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Запуск двух программ последовательно, то есть вначале сервер, а затем браузер не удался, так как браузер запускается раньше и только после некоторого времени страница становится доступной.

Comment: А если просто добавить time.sleep перед запуском браузера, это будет не красиво?

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, все тривиально:

```
def main():
    server = HTTPServer(("", 8080), MyHandler)
    try:
        webbrowser.open("http://localhost:8080/")
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        server.server_close()
```

Суть:

1. Когда мы создали `HTTPServer`, то уже в унаследованном от `SocketServer.TCPServer` конструкторе класса он создал сокет, прибиндил его к адресу и начал на нем слушать (но запросы не обрабатывает);
2. На всякий случай — чтобы отменить поведение из п.1 нужно явно передать конструктору `bind_and_activate=False` и потом руками вызывать `server.server_bind(); server.server_activate()`;
3. Вызов `webbrowser.open()` начал свое дело. Если браузер будет быстрее, чем мы запустим `server.serve_forever()`, то запрос на подключение не барин — подождет в очереди, пока мы не подоспеем.
4. Сокет, если после завершения `serve_forever` планируется завершение работы программы, можно и не закрывать. Это, в общем-то, и так подразумевается.

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте так

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPrequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        ...
def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
        webbrowser.open("html_page_name")
    except:
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Проблема не в том, как открыть браузер, с этим я разобрался, а как запустить его после запуска сервера. В Вашем случае, браузер запуститься только по завершению работы сервера.

Comment: ну я незнаю как у вас запускается сервер, просто подумал что сервер запускает строка "server.serve_forever()" поэтому и поставил туда открытие

можно попробовать так

server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHandler)
webbrowser.open("html_page_name")
server.serve_forever()

а лучше покажите весь код

Comment: Это и есть весь код, обработка Get-запроса будет просто занимать место на странице. Второй ваш вариант тоже не сработает, так как запуск сервера происходит после запуска браузера.